# The 'meta' start tag on line 15 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 177, position 3

Tags: html

I have a piece of great software that I use but the owner deserted it a couple of years ago hence there has not been an upgrade or any maintenance.

In one section I use it come up with the following error message and would like some help in knowing if there is ever a hope that this can be fixed?  It reads....."The 'meta' start tag on line 15 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 177, position 3."  What can be done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems completely and utterly specific to your situation - what is on lines 15 and 177, for instance?

Comment: What can be done: fix the HTML?

Comment: Yeah, HTML. Make sure the 'meta' tag is closed and there is a start tag for 'head'. This is all but a guess though - please be more specific and provide code.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `<meta>` and `<link>` tags may show these errors maybe because they're not closed properly.

Make sure that:

1. Your meta tag is inside the `<head>` `</head>` tags
2. You do close your tag, like this:

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>`

Answer (score 1):

This error probably comes from ClickOnce installer which tries to connect to the server which should contain application manifest and other binary files to be downloaded by setup executable.

Problem is, instead of manifest it receives pure HTML (probably some kind of 404 Not Found page) which is parsed (it's still XML after all) and of course the parse error is reported.

I know this is old answer but it came up with my Google search and seems most relevant to the problem I had. Might save someone some time. In my case it was server side security feature which prevents bots and other malicious software which might scrape our website (and download attachments) depleting available transfer limit.