# How to get specified string in a text

Tags: powershell

I want to get a string from a text (it is a HTML text).

How can I get the email address(n.surname@examplemail.com) and the body (Your message has been delivered to the following recipients:) from the text bellow?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Your message has been delivered to the following recipients:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma">
<p><a href="mailto:n.surname@examplemail.com">Name Surname(n.surname@examplemail.com)</a></p>
<p>Subject: test</p>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to let you know that this might or might not be valid HTML. But for it to work as XML you are missing a <html> tag at the top and the <meta> start tag does not match the </head> end tag. Not a problem if you want to tackle it as a string but if you want to convert it to the xml class you have to fix that first. This could let you navigate it with select-xml and the xml class methods.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I am not generating HTML, it is being generated automatically , so it can't be wrong, but that is not the point.  I do not want to convert it to XML, I just want to get the email and the body from a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is valid (the example you pasted is not so if it's exactly what you got from the app you'll have to correct it somehow).

Working on the corrected example  (added `<html>` tag, corrected `<meta>` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38734094/9902555)):

```bsh
[xml]$html = @"
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Your message has been delivered to the following recipients:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma">
<p><a href="mailto:n.surname@examplemail.com">Name Surname(n.surname@examplemail.com)</a></p>
<p>Subject: test</p>
</font>
</body>
</html>
"@
```

*NOTE: It's usually preferred to work on the text as on XML, instead of string, as you can access objects directly so that's why I convert it using `[xml]` at the beginning.*

If the structure of your file is exactly the same in all cases, you can access the properties you mentioned like this:

```bsh
$body = $html.html.body.p.b.font.'#text'
$address = $html.html.body.font.p.a.href.replace('mailto:','')
```

Alternatively, using `Select-Xml`:

```bsh
$body = (Select-Xml -Xml $html -XPath '//font' | Where-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}).Node.'#text'
$address = (Select-Xml -Xml $html -XPath '//a').Node.href.replace('mailto:','')
```

---

You can also use the following script to correct the structure of your file to be valid HTML:

```bsh
$toBeCorrected = @"
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Your message has been delivered to the following recipients:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma">
<p><a href="mailto:n.surname@examplemail.com">Name Surname(n.surname@examplemail.com)</a></p>
<p>Subject: test</p>
</font>
</body>
</html>
"@
[xml]$correctHTML = '<html>' + ($toBeCorrected -replace '<meta (.*)>','<meta $1 />')
```